# Check battery life for Dell Wireles Keyboard KM717

Tags: keyboard, wireless-keyboard, dell-precision

I am using a Dell Wireless Keyboard KM717

[image: Dell KM717]

The wireless mouse has a tiny red LED that will blink when the battery is running low. I cannot find an equivalent indicator on the keyboard.

How can I tell when the battery is running low on the keyboard?

Comment: Is, “when it stops working” not a suitable answer?

Comment: @Appleoddity that's ok for a personal laptop. But for a coporate laptop that causes a few hours of disruption to every employee that uses the wireless keyboard? Would love to have a solution. I am going to keep spare batteries for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small LED on the back edge of the keyboard, in between the power button and the bluetooth button. You can see it when you turn the keyboard off/on. The LED will turn red and blink when the battery is low.

Comment: Thanks @Carpo , I never realized that